# Run thread periodically

Tags: android, multithreading, web-services

I have a runnable class like this:

```
public class GetUpdatesThread implements Runnable{

@Override
public void run() {
     //call a webservice and parse response

}

}
```

Which I want fire every 10 seconds for instance...

I would like to know how can I manage handlers or runnables or timers in my activity to acomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the timer method called scheduleAtFixedRate from this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29). I am already using it inside my project and it works like charm. You just have to give a starting delay time and a period for it then it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Handler and calling the [sendEmptyMessageDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendEmptyMessageDelayed%28int,%20long%29) method. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#handler) or [two](http://indyvision.net/2010/02/android-threads-tutorial-part-3/) on using Handler. Also check out [Updating the UI from a Timer](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) from the official doc - it covers both approaches with TimerTask and Handler.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this thing is to use AlarmManager class.

1) schedule a AlarmManager with serRepeat method. [link for AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

2) set Broadcast receiver in Alarmmanager, it will call Receiver every particular time duration, now from Receiver you can start your thread .

if you use Timer task and other scheduler, Android will kill them after some time.